Display MS Sharepoint Lists: full width for single field wihtin item-view
I use MS Lists (Sharepoint). When I click on an entry, the editing window opens. I want to sort the fields shown there and vary their width. Unfortunately, that doesn't work. I entered the following in the JSON body, but the title and description remain at 50% display.
I want to achieve the following:
Section 1: display fields half
Section 2: display fields quarter
Section 3: display fields half/quarter
{
        "sections": [
            {
                "displayName": "Main",
                "fields": [
                    "Title",
                    "Description"
                ],
                "displayMode": "oneColumn"
            },
            {
                "displayName": "Fields",
                "fields": [
                    "State",
                    "Category"
                ],
                "displayMode": "twoColumns"
            }
        ],
        "fieldsConfiguration": {
            "Title": {
                "customFormatter": {
                    "elmType": "div",
                    "style": {
                        "width": "100%",
                        "maxWidth": "600px"
                    },
                    "children": [
                        {
                            "elmType": "input",
                            "style": {
                                "width": "100%",
                                "boxSizing": "border-box",
                                "padding": "5px"
                            },
                            "attributes": {
                                "value": "[$Title]"
                            }
                        }
                    ]
                }
            },
            "Description": {
                "customFormatter": {
                    "elmType": "div",
                    "style": {
                        "width": "100%",
                        "maxWidth": "800px"
                    },
                    "children": [
                        {
                            "elmType": "textarea",
                            "style": {
                                "width": "100%",
                                "height": "100px",
                                "padding": "8px",
                                "boxSizing": "border-box",
                                "border": "1px solid #ccc",
                                "borderRadius": "4px",
                                "fontSize": "14px"
                            },
                            "attributes": {
                                "value": "[$Description]"
                            }
                        }
                    ]
                }
            },
            "State": {
                "customFormatter": {
                    "elmType": "div",
                    "style": {
                        "width": "200px"
                    },
                    "children": [
                        {
                            "elmType": "select",
                            "style": {
                                "width": "50%",
                                "padding": "5px"
                            },
                            "attributes": {
                                "value": "[$State]"
                            }
                        }
                    ]
                }
            },
            "Category": {
                "customFormatter": {
                    "elmType": "div",
                    "style": {
                        "width": "150px"
                    },
                    "children": [
                        {
                            "elmType": "select",
                            "style": {
                                "width": "50%",
                                "padding": "5px"
                            },
                            "attributes": {
                                "value": "[$Category]"
                            }
                        }
                    ]
                }
            }
        }
    }

